# Direct internet access feature when creating aws sagemaker notebook instance in private VPC

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am working on terraform sagemaker to create notebook instance. I would like to launch notebook instance in private VPC with direct internet access disabled rather than Amazon manged VPC, but i don't see an option in terraform aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance to disable the direct internet access. Please advise on how to approach this scenario.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Terraform does not yet support the DirectInternetAccess property for the aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance resource. You can track the PR here.[A]

As a work around I am using CloudFormation. If you need to you can wrap the CFN template in the aws_cloudformation_stack resource.[B][C]

Hope this helps out dude.

[A] https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/8618]

[B] https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudformation_stack.html

[C] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sagemaker-notebookinstance.html#cfn-sagemaker-notebookinstance-directinternetaccess

Comment: A little easier to read and use if you to put the links in the answer as hyperlinks using the editor. Then they're clickable links for users.

Comment: Done. Thx for the tip!

Comment: Thank you very much. I will track the PR for DirectInternetAccess property.